# Do GTA IV or EFLC have problems with high FPS? (150+)

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

Grand Theft Auto IV and Episodes from Liberty City didn't ran that good once the game was made available on PC, but after more than 10 years since it was released, we have powerful graphics cards like the 2080 TI and RX 5700.

Let's say that I manage to get 150+ FPS on IV or EFLC, would that cause problems in physics and/or timers (time cycle, missions, etc)?

(GTA 3, VC and SA have problems like this, and I wonder if IV and EFLC also do)

Comment: GTA 4 is dirt cheap, try it out and let us know!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yeah, but the RTX 2080 TI is not.

Comment: Well then I guess you have a non-issue? Running a quick Google search reveals that getting high FPS in that game is nigh impossible anyways since it's such a terrible port.

Comment: I take back what I said about it being dirt cheap, it's not even available for purchase at this time. https://www.theverge.com/2020/1/13/21063810/gta4-steam-games-for-windows-live-pc-gaming-key-generation